# Batch file that deletes all but the last 10 per file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have multiple folders with multiple files with the same name and then a timestamp. Example:

```
foo_2017.01.16.png
foo_2017.01.15.png
foo_2017.01.14.png
bar_2017.01.16.png
bar_2017.01.15.png
bar_2017.01.14.png
file_2017.01.16.png
file_2017.01.15.png
file_2017.01.14.png
```

What I'm needing to do is create a batch file that will parse out only the name before the _timestamp and keep the last 10 of each file name. I'm not very well versed in batch and could really use some help here. The Date Modified for every file is the same, so I cannot just say keep only the last 10 days, otherwise I could handle that.

***EDIT:***

I have a batch file that deletes files in a specific folder older than 28 days that looks like the following, I just do not know how to modify it to iterate through for each file name specifically and to not go by Date Modified:

```
/c echo @FILE
forfiles -p "C:\workspace\SeleniumTestResults" -s -m *.* /D -28 /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Again, this batch is definitely not my area

Comment: Help implies you've done something yourself, so post your batch file by editing your question accordingly and ask for specific help on the parts of your code that are giving you problems.

Comment: I attached a copy of a batch file I'm using to delete all files based on Date Modified, I just do not know how to do what my question details

Comment: Do not extend or change the scope of a question, because already posted answers may appear incomplete or wrong then! Post another question instead! In addition, never include solutions into a question; provide your own answer instead! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
REM create some files for testing:
break>foo_2017.01.16.png
break>foo_2017.01.15.png
break>foo_2017.01.14.png
break>bar_2017.01.16.png
break>bar_2017.01.15.png
break>bar_2017.01.14.png
break>file_2017.01.16.png
break>file_2017.01.15.png
break>file_2017.01.14.png
dir *.png

set keep=2

for /f "delims=_" %%a in ('dir /b *.png') do (
  for /f "skip=%keep% delims=" %%b in ('dir /b /o-n "%%~a*.png"') do del "%%b"
)
dir *.png
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the "for" loop in the answer run in each sub-directory that matches "Screenshots"? This works great and I thought I could figure out how to scan through all subfolders and execute the 'for' loops you provided on all "Screenshot" directories, but I am not having any luck figuring this out. I have edited my question with an example folder structure. Any further help would be very much appreciated. --- I have added on to my question. Also, should I create a new question for this?

Comment: I figured it out. I'll put the solution in the question

Comment: No @DustinN., do not put a solution into your question! Post your own answer instead!